# How to close Drop Down using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

The dropdown block is working fine because, I can see that the element is clicked and the drop down appears with check box type options populated, however after the selection it does not close. I have also attached the HTML snippet of code after the dropdown block is opened below -

[image]

The below is the UI screen.

[image]

The below is the HTML snippet to the Prefix field:
[image]

This is the code i am trying with:

```
element(by.model("requestType.whoCanInitiate")).click();
element.all(by.repeater("user in usersList")).get(3).click();
element(by.model("requestType.icon")).click();
element.all(by.repeater("icon in icons")).get(0).click();
element(by.name("prefix")).sendKeys("admin");
```

Comment: share your UI Screen so that will get the better idea on the problem. And confirm that your query is to close the dropdown.

Comment: @Madhan i have added the UI screen.

Comment: Try clicking the `prefix` text after selecting the user from the dropdown.

Comment: clicking prefix is failing saying 'is not clickable at point (900, 502). Other element would receive the click:'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that dropdown can be closed by clicking somewhere outside or pressing ESC button, try the following examples

```
 $('body').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE);
```

or

```
 $('body').click();
```

or close by clicking on material backdrop element

```
 $('md-backdrop').click();
```

Comment: I used the following code: 
element(by.model("requestType.icon")).click();
element.all(by.repeater("icon in icons")).get(0).click($('md-backdrop').click());

Comment: @JagdeepBhatta that's correct, now if you want to close the dropdown simply attach one of the snippets from above after you did choose options

Comment: click($('md-backdrop').click())
I used this after selecting the options. 2nd code was for selecting the option and passed to click command for the 'md-backdrop', or 'body' or any other element like 'prefix', but all failed saying other element would receive the click inside the options dropdown itself.

Comment: why did you cover the code in another click? this does make any sense, just put it there as it is

Comment: ok. I put the code as it is after click the option separately, still fails saying same error message.

Comment: can't be the problem, especially for pressing ESC button, post the whole code that you have into your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186904/discussion-between-lunin-roman-and-jagdeep-bhatta).

Comment: for cases where `Key.ESCAPE` is not enabled on the UI I think the only option is to use `browser.actions().mouseMove(elementRef, {x: xOffset, y: yOffset}).click().perform()` so the offsets points to some place outside the dialog.